# iTunes Connect: Exclude iPad 2 from supported devices

Tags: ipad, app-store-connect

I just posted my first application on Apple store. It is for iPads only, so I chose that in xCode.
It works good on iPad 3 and newer, but crashes on iPad 1 and iPad 2.
On this site I found out that iPad 1 "auto-focus-camera" and "bluetooth-le", but I think that it's not a good practice to state that my app requires auto-focus-camera, when it actually doesn't.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html

So how can I exclude iPad 1 and iPad 2 from supported devices?

Comment: You can exclude the iPad 1 based on a required OS version greater than 5.1.1; I don't know about the iPad 2.  But why not fix the crash?

Comment: iPad 2 supports the latest (i.e. 9) iOS. So you need to support it without a crash. If there's functionality that the iPad 2 can't do, you should treat it and tell the user, but the app shouldn't crash, as Phillip Mills just commented.

Comment: I have a problem with memory limits when I do long sound recordings. Looks like I will need to fix that =)